# Multiple form into one view: how to handle a field error?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a model like this:

```
class PersonneTravel(models.Model):
    personne = models.ForeignKey(Personne, verbose_name=_(u'Person'))
    travel = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_(u'Travel'))
    date_start = models.DateTimeField(default=None, null=True, blank=True,
                                      editable=True, verbose_name=_(u"Start"))
    date_end = models.DateTimeField(default=None, null=True, blank=True,
                                    editable=True, verbose_name=_(u"End"))
    comments = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True,
                                verbose_name=_(u'Comments'))
```

I display a list of all the travels of one person.
What I wanted to do is to give the possibility to **online**-edit any of the travels, or to add one, **into one view**.

Here's how I did:

- create a Form: `class PersonneTravelForm` with all fields
- create a view `class IndexView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.FormView):`
- overload `get_context_data` where I create all those forms like this:

  ```
  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
      context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
      context['travels'] = []
      for ptf in PersonneTravel.objects.filter(
          personne__user=self.request.user,
      ):
          context['travels'].append({
              'obj': ptf,
              'form': PersonneTravelForm({
                  'pk': ptf.pk,
                  'travel': ptf.travel.value,
                  'date_start': ptf.date_start,
                  'date_end': ptf.date_end,
                  'comments': ptf.comments,
              })
          })
  ```
- from there in the template, I make a loop:

  ```
  {% for v in travels %}
      {% with v.form as form %}
          {% include "my_home/travels/travel_form.html" %}
      {% endwith %}{# form #}
  {% endfor %}
  ```
- and in the file `travel_form.html` I display the form
- I've added a bit of javascript with a button "edit" for each form and we the user clicks on it, I `slideDown()` the form
- When the users clicks "`update`" to update one travel, the corresponding form is sent as a `POST`. In the form code, I've created all filters in the form `def clean_XXXX(self):` with all fields properly "cleaned"
- In the view, I analyze the fields in `def form_valid(self, form)`:

  - if there's a `pk` in the fields it's for update or delete

    - if all other fields are None I delete
    - if any field is not None then I update
  - if there's no `pk` it's for add a new record, I add one

My big and only problem here is when there's an error: if I try to add an error while checking the form, and there's a problem I do this, for example:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    fc = form.cleaned_data
    d_start = fc['date_start']
    d_end = fc['date_end']
    comments = fc.get('comments', None)

    if d_end and d_start:
        if d_end > datetime.datetime.now().date() > d_start:
            form.add_error('date_start', _(u"Can't start in the past..."))
            form.add_error('date_end', _(u"...and end in the future!"))
            return super(IndexView, self).form_invalid(form)
```

Everything seems fine... except that the error field goes **always** into the "add new" blank form, never to the good "edit" form. How would you handle this?

Comment: What you need are Django Formsets https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: @MuhammadTahir you should really repost your comment as an answer.

Comment: @OlivierPons First point: `generic.FormView` is for handling a single form (`dango.fomr` that is), but you have a list for forms. Also you're not prefixing your forms so you cannot even know which of them was submitted. You could of course sovle both problems, but Django has formsets exactly for this use case.

Comment: @MuhammadTahir may I ask you to answer below so I can check your answer as valid?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers You're right, but I've gone too far to break everything with "clean code", I dont have time for that. Tons of comment in my code, but here's how I dealt with that: in the __init__ of my view, I check if there's a form in kwargs, and if that form has a pk field and errors property not empty. If so, I take it apart and override with `kwargs['form'] = PersonneTravelForm({})`. And later on, when I create all my forms through a Query, if I find a row with the same id, I assign the form_error instead of constructing one. This is ugly I know.

Comment: "I've gone too far to break everything with "clean code", I dont have time for that" - well, your call but from experience, this _always_ end up spending more time trying to make the ugly solution work THEN debugging it once it's deployed than it would take to just ditch the ugly code and start anew with the clean solution...

Comment: If you're on your own, if you have your own company, if you've sold a big product and have to put it online in a very short time, you think this way: "it's ugly, I need to present the product, I'll rewrite that only if I earn enough money with this product". I've been an employee for 15 years, and always thought like you. Now that I'm on my own, I cant tell you (**unfortunately**) this is not the same deal and you just have to do things *on time* otherwise you won't earn enough money to pay your rent. It's life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [Django Formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/) for this purpose, when you are handling list of forms of a same type. Formset gives you built in features to create new records as well as delete and update older ones.